# What is Melman wearing on his feet, and why?

Tags: madagascar

In [*Madagascar* (2005)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0351283/), after Marty runs away from the zoo, we see Alex go over the wall, while Gloria breaks through it.  When Melman follows Gloria through the wall, he's got something on his feet.  Does anyone know what that "something" is, and why it's there?  It looks like cement blocks, but I don't understand why they're there.

Comment: An image would be useful here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

IIRC, they were tissue boxes that Melman used as '[Safety Foot Covers](https://www.uline.ca/Grp_515/Foot-Protection)' which is in keeping with Melman as a *'hypochondriac giraffe with infinite phobias'*. If you look closely, you can see the distinctive oval openings in the top of the boxes that are characteristic of tissue boxes.

[image]

This is analogous to the urban myth that Howard Hughes, in his most hypochondrial period late in life, would walk around using tissue boxes as footwear.

---

<sub>In the Dreamworks Madagascar video game series, two of the rewards that the Melman character can achieve are the NYC clock and **tissue box shoes**.</sub>

Comment: Thanks!  I was convinced they were cinderblocks but I couldn't figure out where he got them or why he'd put them on his feet.  This makes sense now.

Comment: I've had time to rewatch the first 20-odd minutes of that animated feature. The exit over and through the zoo wall is the first we see of the 'footwear'. He has them for a while afterwards (see outside the subway's public bathroom above) but disappear shortly thereafter with no explanation.

Comment: For a moment as he is leaving you can [see on the side of a box](https://imgur.com/PFHeqgX) the word "Noseblows".

Comment: @Jeeped - One of them he shakes off when trying to get on the subway, another is replaced by the busker's drum when he gets out of the subway car.  I'm fairly (though not completely) certain he's still wearing them in Grand Central Station.  After that scene he doesn't show up again until they've been loaded on the boat, so by then it's assumed they've been removed by zoo personnel.